# With FDT, How Do I Prevent Packaging For Mobile Applications (iOS & Android) 

Tags: ant, launch, fdt

When working with the FDT FREE version, how do I run a configuration which only compiles the SWF and doesn't package an .IPA or .APK.

Is there any way of do this?

For example, I would like to have 2 launch methods, one that only compiles the swf and after it processes some ant script to update resources, and another that final compiles and packages the app.

Answer (score 0):

Set the launcher platform to 'Adobe AIR Desktop' and choose 'Do not launch'. You may need to set the project type to 'AIR All' in order to achieve this. This will work for most scenarios.
[image]
[image]